# Tensorflow Official Distributed Mask-RCNN get error : Requested more than 0 entries

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, mask, distributed

I use official distributed mult-worker-gpu MaskRCNN code from https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tree/master/models/official/mask_rcnn repository. In this repository we have mask_rcnn_main.py file and we use this file to start training operation.

In this file has a multi parameters. We select multi_worker_gpu flag.
After start training get a error :

```
Requested more than 0 entries, but params is empty.  Params shape: [0,218,231]
     [[{{node parser/GatherNd_2}}]]
     [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
```

Our Dataset (coco tfrecod)

Have you any idea ?

Comment: Given Tensorflow Tutorial uses TPU, you need to do little modification to your code before using Multi GPU, Since it uses `TPUEstimator`. Make sure you made all necessary changes. Thanks!